# Transform SQL Server Data With Headers as First Column and the Data as New columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, transform, unpivot

I want to transform Data:

```
ID  EmpName   EmpPhoneNumber  EmpSiblings
1   Jack      4444444         Amy
1   Jack      6666666         Judy
```

into

```
EmployeeParamater     Value1    Value2
ID                    1         1
EmpName               Jack      Jack
EmployeePhoneNumber   4444444   6666666  
EmpSiblings           Amy       Judy
```

In SQL Server, When I unpivot the data I get:

```
EmpName - Jack
EmpName - Jack
```

Comment: format tables properly

Comment: This type of transformation is usually better done at the application level (although you can do it in SQL).

Comment: I have to do it in the SQL layer because I do not have an application layer.

Comment: See that
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx